# How to get the type as nullable when using Expando object

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, nullable, expandoobject

I am having the collection which is `dynamic` type. I have stored the double values in the collection. For some records, I am not store the data to it. Now I need to get this type as `nullable` double to perform some operations. Is there any way to get the data property type as `nullable` while using `Expando` object ?

```
ObservableCollection<dynamic> dynamicItems = new ObservableCollection<dynamic>();
for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++)
{
    dynamic data = new ExpandoObject();
    if (j == 2)
    {
        // not store the value when j is 2.
    }
    else
    {
        data.colValues = 12.2 * j;                  
    }

    dynamicItems.Add(data);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just create a class to store this information?

Comment: i am bind this collection "dynamicItems" to the datagrid

Answer (score 3):

You can try *casting* to `Double?` and then check if `colValues == null`:

```
   ...
   if (j == 2)
   {
        // not store the value when j is 2.
       data.colValues = new Nullable<Double>(); // or (Double?) null;
   }
   else
   {
       data.colValues = (Double?) (12.2 * j);                  
   }
   ...

   // if colValues exists
   if (null != data.colValues) {
     Double v = data.colValues;
     ... 
   }
```

Another way is *doing nothing* and then check if the field (i.e. `colValues`) *exists*, but, IMHO, it's a not that *good* implementation:

```
   if (j == 2)
   {
        // not store the value when j is 2. - literally do nothing
   }
   else
   {
       data.colValues = 12.2 * j;                  
   }

   ... 
   // if colValues exists
   if ((data as IDictionary<String, Object>).ContainsKey("colValues")) {
     Double v = data.colValues; // or var v = data.colValues;
     ... 
   }
```

Comment: Hi, can you share how to change this generically ?

Comment: @Elavarasan M: the *second* way doesn't depend on `colValues` type at all; the *first* way requires that `colValues` being `struct`

Comment: I need to perform some operations based on the the type. But while adding value, i am not giving the type. but when perform some operation, i need to get the type of colvalues as nullable double. is any option to get this ?? Thanks in Advance

Comment: @Elavarasan M: `Double?` (or `Nullable<Double>`) could be used as *nullable double* (see my 1st chunk of code)

Comment: ok. But i am not give its type while store the value. if i get the type of colvalues, its returned double. but actually its nullable double, because i have used expandoobject and not store the value to colvalues in some condition. if i get the type means, i need as nullable double. I mean, in runtime i get the type of colvalues based on the value means its returned the double. can you share, if any suggestion. sorry for the troubles.

Comment: @Elavarasan M: if you don't know types (or at least don't want to get them from columns, create nullable *wraps* on values etc.) you can use my *2nd chunk* (it's *type independent*): just do not store values. However, later you have to check if value has been stored or not (and so should be treated as `null`, absent etc.).

Comment: In my situation, i get the type based on the colvalues. Now its returned as double. For the same, if i use integer with nullable like (double? colvalues) means the type of colvalues based on the record means it returned as nullable double. Like wise i need to retrieve the type as nullable double with expando object.

Comment: @Elavarasan M: eh, if you have `int` you can use `int?` etc. In case you don't want to know anything about the *type* try *the second way* and just put `var v = data.colValues;` instead of `Double v = data.colValues;`. In all the cases you're working with *dynamic* instance, i.e.*late binding*

Comment: yes i have used like you mentioned. if i get the type by data.colValues, its returned double only. but i need to retrieve that as nullable, because it have the nullable value. is any way to retreive that as nullable double ? sorry for the lot of confusions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88667/discussion-between-elavarasan-m-and-dmitry-bychenko).